# spring filter being invoked for all url's and not matching the url pattern

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I am registering a `@bean` using `FilterRegistrationBean` in my Spring Boot app with tomcat:

```
Filter filter = new MyFilter() { ****populate my-header-bean from request***** };

List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
urlPatterns.add("/hr/*");

FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
registration.setFilter(filter);
registration.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
```

Even after a `urlPattern` is specified, the filter is being invoked for all URLs , its behaving like `/*`. Is there any other way to register a filter for filtering HTTP headers for the URLs matching `/hr/*`.
Also my-header-bean in the filter to be available as spring-autowire inside my controllers.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: no, did not.still trying to find

Comment: finally resolved this, the url patterns does not effect,have to find an alternate way to do this.
Basically add filter ,but inside filter skip accessing/rejecting header values based on similar logic as below

uri.startsWith("/swagger")|| uri.startsWith("/webjars")||uri.startsWith("/v2/api-docs");
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally resolved this, the url patterns does not effect,have to find an alternate way to do this.
Basically add filter and do not worry url patterns ,but inside filter skip accessing/rejecting header values based on similar logic as below

```
 uri.startsWith("/swagger")|| uri.startsWith("/webjars")||uri.startsWith("/v2/api-docs");
}
```

worked in my scenario..can work for a few ppl having similar problem :)